# OR Queries in Parse for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode7

I am trying to create a compound query for my app to search the list of PFUsers in my Parse database whose firstname or lastname or username contain a specific word entered using the keyboard.

To do that, my code is:

```
let usernameQuery = PFUser.query()
usernameQuery!.whereKey("username", containsString: searchBar.text?.lowercaseString)

let firstnameQuery = PFUser.query()
usernameQuery!.whereKey("firstname", containsString: searchBar.text?.lowercaseString)

let lastnameQuery = PFUser.query()
usernameQuery!.whereKey("Lastname", containsString: searchBar.text?.lowercaseString)

let query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([usernameQuery, firstnameQuery, lastnameQuery])
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{ ......
```

My problem is that i have an error creating the Array of Subqueries with the following error message: `Cannot convert value of type '[PFQuery?]' to expected argument type '[AnyObject]'`
I'm not that familiar yet with Swift and was wondering if anyone had any clue on how to solve that by any chance?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try unwrapping the optional PFQueries.

Comment: @LyndseyScott do you mean doing in 3 independant queries? Like search in username, then search in firstname and finally search in lastname?

Comment: Hi so this doesn't seem like it would theoretically work. Say I paste in "Paul Jones". firstnameQuery wouldn't pick it up, bc the string contains " Jones" and lastnameQuery wouldn't pick it up, bc the string contains "Paul ". How did you end up doing this? If I may ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple issues going on here.

In terms of syntax, notice the `!` in `usernameQuery!.whereKey`. This is telling us that `usernameQuery` is an optional value which needs to be unwrapped.

So the correct compound query should be

```
let query = PFQuery.orQueryWithSubqueries([usernameQuery!, firstnameQuery!, lastnameQuery!])
```

Next, you will want to call `whereKey` on each separate query, rather than all of them on `usernameQuery`. I'm guessing those are classic copy/paste typos :)

Comment: thanks a lot for both the answer and the explanation! Really appreciate! i get my transition from objectiveC to swift still needs a lot of work! ;)